# Rendering multiple VBOs in one draw call in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, video, vbo

I have a few hundred VBOs.  I want to only draw a subset of the VBOs each frame.

Is there anything faster than binding and drawing each VBO?  Is there a batched draw command for multiple VBOs?

1. How do I bind multiple VBOs
2. Is there a version of `glMultiDrawElements` for sets of VBOs?

Comment: Why are you looking to do this? Is it getting slow or something? How many polys per VBO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is not, because there is only one GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding point and only one buffer can be bound to it at anytime.